# How to get 2 most recent records of each related row

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say I have these 2 tables:

`Users: id, name`

`Posts: id, user_id, created_at`

I am trying to get 2 most recent posts of each user.  I have the relationship models set up correctly. At first I thought I could just use `->take(2)` but that only returns 2 rows from the whole query.

This is what I have now:

```
$user->load(['posts' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}]);
```

That will return all posts for each user. It's really not a problem right now but if users have hundreds or thousands of posts, that will become a memory hog quickly.

What's the best way to get last 2 records of each user with hopefully using eager loading?  I could easily do it by fetching last 2 records of each user but that's too many queries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

Note: the number of queries run will be number of users returned + 1;

```
// Get all users with posts
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function($query) {
    $query->whereNotNull('user_id');
})->get();

// Add just the 2 most recent posts to the collection
$users = $user->map(function ($user) {
    $user->timeEntries = $user->posts()
                              ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                              ->take(2)
                              ->get();

    return $user;
});
```

Unfortunately, there is no direct way in Eloquent to limit the number of records returned from a relationship.

An alternative would be to write the query using plain old SQL so you could do it in just 1 query.

Remember, Eloquent is a tool and as such, it *may* not always be the best for the job. This is especially true when it comes to advanced queries. Just because you CAN do it in Eloquent doesn't mean you should. I think a lot of us developers think that because we're buying into this framework that has a really nice ORM that we have to use it otherwise we're doing it "wrong" and it's not the "Laravel way" (or whatever framework we may be using, PHP or otherwise), but that's not as all the case. **Simple wins.**

Comment: Well I'm trying to decide the best way to do it.  I have two other relations I am loading to the user which work great with eager loading, so I would probably have to scrap all those and just make 1 bigger sql query and try to grab it all in one go.

Comment: Curious as to why the downvotes? If there's a way I can improve this answer I'd like to know (especially since the OP accepted it).